# Google App Scripts Scroll

Tags: html, scroll, infinite-scroll

I'm currently using Google App Scripts to run a document with multiple dropdown menus that have scripts that make it easier for me to quickly insert paragraphs of typical information that I write often.

My problem is that under one of my "submenus," I have too many "items" that require a scroll to get to the bottom of the "submenu" list. Right now, my only solution is to either delete items to fit my page or create a new submenu. Is there a way to have the one "submenu" with many "items" and have it scroll down to the last item when I am accessing it in my googledoc?